# Creating docker images with java application

Tags: java, spring, docker

Hello i'm just saw a video on docker and i wanted to write a simple program in java to create a docker image, get a list of containers and so on. Would this be possible using java?And if so can i use spring-boot? From the look at it Docker is purely command line and I don't know how to start but my idea was to write a simple java server and send packets to the docker daemon to be able to create images, get a list of containers and so on. Is this the right way or can it be done using spring-boot by calling the apis. If anyone has implemented the rest api using docker any suggestions or a sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [`spotify/docker-client`](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client), which implements most of the [docker commandline](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/) in java.

It doesn't use [SpringBoot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) though.